# Why is Python pandas assigning arbitrary time information to datetime object?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timedelta

Python pandas (0.24.1) is adding a seemingly arbitrary number of hours, minutes, and seconds to my datetime objects. This seems unexpected as default behavior; I would expect the time component to default to midnight (00:00:00). Is this a bug?

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame( {'yr': [2019, 2019],
                    'mo': [9, 9],
                    'dy': [25, 26]}     )

df['dtime'] = ( pd.to_datetime(df['yr'],format='%Y')
               +pd.to_timedelta(df['mo']-1,unit='M')
               +pd.to_timedelta(df['dy']-1,unit='d') )


print('pandas version == '+pd.__version__)
df

################################################
OUTPUT:
################################################

pandas version == 0.24.1
yr  mo  dy  dtime
0   2019    9   25  2019-09-25 11:52:48
1   2019    9   26  2019-09-26 11:52:48
```

Answer (score 2):

Problem is with converting months, here is used `'rounded'` year (because leap year) and divided by `12` for `'rounded'` month:

```
print (pd.to_timedelta(365.2425, unit='d') / 12)
30 days 10:29:06

print (pd.to_timedelta(1, unit='M'))
30 days 10:29:06

print (pd.to_timedelta(df['mo']-1,unit='M'))
0   243 days 11:52:48
1   243 days 11:52:48
Name: mo, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

Better solution is use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) with `year`, `monht` and `day` columns and if necessary filter it by subset with `list(d.values())` (if another columns in real data):

```
d = {'yr':'year', 'mo':'month', 'dy':'day'}
df['dtime'] = pd.to_datetime(df.rename(columns=d)[list(d.values())])

print (df)
     yr  mo  dy      dtime
0  2019   9  25 2019-09-25
1  2019   9  26 2019-09-26
```

Answer (score 2):

To add detail as to the issue with timedelta that Jezrael pointed out above, the issue with the month conversion is as follows: Pandas timedelta defines a month as 1/12 of a year, which is 365.2425 days based on leap year logic.

243 days 11:52:48 is 21037968 seconds.

```
>>> 243*60*60*24+11*60*60+52*60+48
21037968
```

Some dimensional analysis confirms this is 8/12 of a year that is 365.2425 days long.

```
>>> 21037968/((8/12)*365.2425*60*60*24)
1.0
```

As noted above, use to_datetime to avoid this.